# Unix Shell: If Conditions grep & test

Tags: shell, unix, uc4

I have the following problem: I try to send mails with different content and to different recipients, when the following conditions are met:

- a specific string in a logfile is NOT found and a specific file exists
- a specific string in a logfile is NOT found and a specific file does NOT exist
- a specific string in a logfile is found and a specific file exists
- a specific string in a logfile is found and a specific file does NOT exist

The specific string is found in the newest logfile, the specific file was or was not created in a job prior to this one. The problem is: it worked when put in a .sh file and starting it via command line in putty, but since I transfered it to UC4, it doesn´t work. It keeps choosing wrong options.

Here´s my code (simplified, without the email part)

```
if [ ! grep -q 'errors: 0' "/mypath/$(ls -t /mypath/ | head -n1)" ] && test -e "/mypath2/outtakes.csv"; then
        
        echo 'error + filtered data'

elif [ ! grep -q 'errors: 0' "/mypath/$(ls -t /mypath/ | head -n1)" ] && ! test -e "/mypath2/outtakes.csv"; then
        
        echo 'error + no filtered data'


elif [ grep -q 'errors: 0' "/mypath/$(ls -t /mypath/ | head -n1)" ] && test -e "mypath2/outtakes.csv"; then

        echo 'no errors + filtered data'


else
        
        echo 'no errors + no filtered data'

fi
```

I tried to change brackets, test conditions individually and individually, they worked. It must have to do with the chain of conditions.

Comment: Instead of `if [ ! grep ...`, you just want `if ! grep ...`

Answer (score 0):

`if` checks the return status of the command.  `[` is a command.  The expression `if [ ! grep -q 'errors: 0' ...` does not make much sense; it executes `[` with the arguments `!`, `grep`, etc.  It does *not* execute `grep`.  If you want to check the return status of `grep`, just do:

```
if ! grep ....
```

This will execute grep and branch based on its return value.  Because of the `!`, the `if` branch is entered if `grep` returns non-zero.